# Get nth element of a collection in Cypher

Tags: collections, neo4j, cypher

Using [Cypher 1.8](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.8/cypher-query-lang.html), there are some functions working on collections and returning a single element:

**`HEAD( expression )`:**

```
START a=node(2)
RETURN a.array, head(a.array)
```

**`LAST( expression )`:**

```
START a=node(2)
RETURN a.array, last(a.array)
```

However, I could not find a function to return the **nth element** of a collection. What am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no good way to do that at the moment. Please submit a feature request at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j

I've seen people do head(tail(tail(tail(coll)))), and while it's probably acceptably fast, it still makes me a little ill to see in a query, especially if you're talking about the 17th element or worse.

Example:
http://console.neo4j.org/r/bbo6o4

**Update:**
Here's a way to do it using reduce and range. It makes it so you can give a parameter for nth at least, even though it still makes me cringe:

```
start n=node(*) 
with collect(n) as allnodes 
return head(reduce(acc=allnodes, x in range(1,3): tail(acc)));
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/8erfup

**Update 2 (8/31/2013):**
The new collection syntax is now merged into 2.0 and will be theoretically be a part of M05! So, you'll be able to do:

```
start n=node(*)
with collect(n) as allnodes
return allnodes[3]; // or slices, like [1..3]
```

I'll add a link to the snapshot documentation when it gets updated.

Comment: @fynn I've submitted a pull request with this function. Syntax is like: `nth(17, a.array)`. https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/443

Answer (score 2):

I've just come across this old question, and for the benefit of anyone else recently coming across it... it seems the list support has improved.

From the [Cypher 4 list docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-lists-general):

> Cypher has comprehensive support for lists.

^ Sidenote: I think that's list comprehensions pun? ;-)

They go on to give an example showing how you'd access the n'th element of a list:

> To access individual elements in the list, we use the square brackets again. This will extract from the start index and up to but not including the end index.
> ... we’ll use the range function. It gives you a list containing all numbers between given start and end numbers. Range is inclusive in both ends.

```
RETURN range(0, 10)[3]
^ returns "3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, with the release of [APOC Procedures 3.3.0.2](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/tag/3.3.0.2) you can use [aggregation functions](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_aggregation_functions).

This way, you can do thinks like:

```
create (:Node {node_id : 1}),
    (:Node {node_id : 2}),
    (:Node {node_id : 3});

match(n:Node)
with n order by n.node_id
// returns {"node_id":2}  
return apoc.agg.nth(n, 1);
```

or:

```
match(n:Node)
with n order by n.node_id
// returns {"node_id":1} 
// you can also use apoc.agg.last
return apoc.agg.first(n);
```

To work with lists `UNWIND` the list first:

```
with ['fist', 'second', 'third'] as list
unwind list as value
// returns 'second'
return apoc.agg.nth(value, 1);
```